# Svelte 4 Migration Issues and hosting on Digital Ocean

Tags: svelte, digital-ocean, sveltekit, svelte-4, sveltekit-adapter-static

I am experiencing issues with my Svelte 4 Project, migrated to Svelte 4 by a previous developer.

Site it hosted on DigitalOcean App Platform. I am having issues getting it to build or run on the dev server locally (as well as DO).

Running on Node 16.

This is my package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev --port 3000",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "start": "node index.js",
        "build:digitalocean": "npm install --production=false && npm run build && npm ci",
        "test": "npm run test:integration && npm run test:unit",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --write .",
        "test:integration": "playwright test",
        "test:unit": "vitest",
        "postbuild": "node --experimental-json-modules ./generate-sitemap.js"
    },
    "exports": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "@beyonk/svelte-google-analytics": "^2.6.4",
        "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "1.30.4",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.1.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^2.0.1",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.0",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
        "algoliasearch": "^4.22.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
        "cookie": "^0.6.0",
        "cssnano": "^6.0.3",
        "daisyui": "^4.6.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.35.1",
        "fast-glob": "^3.3.2",
        "instantsearch.js": "^4.64.0",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
        "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
        "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
        "lodash.uniq": "^4.5.0",
        "lodash.uniqby": "^4.7.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
        "postcss": "^8.4.33",
        "postcss-color-mod-function": "^3.0.3",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^9.3.0",
        "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
        "prettier": "^3.2.4",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^3.1.2",
        "query-string": "^8.1.0",
        "rollup-plugin-svelte": "7.1.5",
        "svelte": "^4.2.9",
        "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
        "tslib": "^2.4.1",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "vitest": "^0.2.0",
        "xmlbuilder2": "^3.1.1"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "serve": "^14.2.1",
        "yarn": "^1.22.21"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "16.x",
        "npm": "~8.x"
    }
}
```

`npm install` works fine.

`npm dev` works too. But when navigating to the site, I get

> 500 Internal Error

In the terminal, I see

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'siteConfig')
    at C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\src\routes\+layout.svelte:23:38
    at Object.$$render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:156:16)
    at C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\.svelte-kit\generated\root.svelte:44:40
    at $$render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:156:16)
    at Object.render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:164:17)
    at Module.render_response (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\page\render.js:170:29)
    at async Module.render_page (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\page\index.js:286:10)
    at async resolve (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:407:18)
    at async Module.respond (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:20)
    at async file:///C:/Users/devel/Repos/365-Autmotive-Marketing/frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:510:22
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'siteConfig')
    at C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\src\routes\+layout.svelte:23:38
    at Object.$$render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:156:16)
    at C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\.svelte-kit\generated\root.svelte:44:40
    at $$render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:156:16)
    at Object.render (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\svelte\src\runtime\internal\ssr.js:164:17)
    at Module.render_response (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\page\render.js:170:29)
    at async Module.respond_with_error (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\page\respond_with_error.js:83:10)
    at async Module.render_page (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\page\index.js:305:10)
    at async resolve (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:407:18)
    at async Module.respond (C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\node_modules\@sveltejs\kit\src\runtime\server\respond.js:274:20)
svelte config changed, restarting vite dev-server. changed file: C:\Users\devel\Repos\365-Autmotive-Marketing\frontend-user-interface-for-classifieds-sites\svelte.config.js
```

`npm run build` works too. Encountering the same issues, when utilizing `npm run preview` of course.

I am deploying this to DigtalOcean as well (automatic via Github).

The build log is similar.

```
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'siteConfig')
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js:97:39
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at Object.$$render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:127:18)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js:57:121
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at $$render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:127:18)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at Object.render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:135:20)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at render_response (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1401:34)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async render_page (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2219:12)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async resolve2 (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2833:24)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async respond (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2719:22)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async visit (file:///workspace/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/core/postbuild/prerender.js:203:20)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'siteConfig')
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js:97:39
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at Object.$$render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:127:18)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js:57:121
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at $$render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:127:18)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at Object.render (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js:135:20)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at render_response (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1401:34)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async respond_with_error (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1771:12)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async render_page (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2236:12)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async resolve2 (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2833:24)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │     at async respond (file:///workspace/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2719:22)
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ Handling HTTP error: 500 on path: /, referred from null as a linked
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/.vite/manifest.json                                       4.20 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/helpers.2cb07c31.css                0.10 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_page.e8a8c33b.css                  0.87 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/_app/immutable/assets/_layout.079db109.css              136.67 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/hooks.server.js                                    0.00 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/internal.js                                               0.19 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/fallbacks/error.svelte.js                         0.47 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/blog/_page.js                               0.59 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/stores.js                                          0.66 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_page.js                                    0.68 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.server.js                           1.05 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/helpers.js                                         1.31 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index.js                                           1.40 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/search-store.js                                    1.48 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/blog/author/_...author_/_page.svelte.js     2.64 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/inventory/_...vehicles_/_page.server.js     3.85 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/blog/blog-post/_...post_/_page.svelte.js    4.51 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/ssr.js                                             5.35 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js                                        9.03 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/blog/_page.svelte.js                       10.23 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js                          10.73 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_page.svelte.js                            15.09 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/inventory/_...vehicles_/_page.svelte.js    28.95 kB
[2024-03-13 16:44:30] │ .svelte-kit/output/server/index.js
```

If anyone has any insight on this, I would greatly appreciate some input, as I am new to Svelte and DigitalOcean.

I tried changing the @sveltejs/kit related dependencies. Previous developer supposedly had the site running locally with:

```
        "@sveltejs/kit": "1.30.4",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.1.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-static": "^2.0.1",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "^2.0.0",
```

However, the DigitalOcean App Platform server uses Node 16, of which @sveltejs/kit is incompatible. Had to change the packages accordingly, through trial and error.

He was using a higher version of Node, which is why there were build issues related to Node version in the DO build logs previously.

Those issues were resolved with the changes to package.json I made (downgrading @sveltejs/kit and peer dependency versions, to align with Node 16).

However, I am now seeing the issues I posted about.

I am unfamiliar with this siteConfig object, and am not sure why that suddenly doesn't work.

Edit:

After further investigation I have discovered this:

The $page object in my `+layout.svelte.js` file seems to be missing data.

When I output `$page`:

```
  data: {
    status: 500,
    error: 'No site config found for 365carshop.com',
    body: { components: [Array], metaData: [Object] }
  },
```

This is my svelte.config.js:

```
    import node from '@sveltejs/adapter-node';
import staticAdapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

const adapter =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? staticAdapter({ fallback: 'index.html' })
    : node();

const config = {
  kit: {
    adapter,

    paths: {
      base: ''
    },
    prerender: {
      // Implementing handleHttpError
      handleHttpError({ status, path, referrer, referenceType }) {
        console.log(`Handling HTTP error: ${status} on path: ${path}, referred from ${referrer} as a ${referenceType}`);
        if (status === 404) {
          return true; // Suppress the error
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

I am not sure where the issue lies, or why this would be an issue after migrating?

Comment: Note -  I removed some of the package.json meta information for the sake of this post. (name, version, author, etc..)